# Cannot talk to rtnetlink : Operation not supported

Tags: networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to use netem tool on my windows subsytem for linux.
This is the command I tried

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem delay 100ms
```

I am getting this error

```
Cannot talk to rtnetlink : Operation not supported
```

Can anyone help? Is this error coming because I am using windows subsytem for linux?

Comment: The issue you're facing with the `tc qdisc` command in WSL seems to be a compatibility issue. WSL, particularly WSL2, might not fully support certain network operations, including those related to `netem` and `tc qdisc`.

You might need to use a native Linux environment or a virtual machine that provides full Linux kernel capabilities, as WSL2 might not support all the features needed for `netem` and `tc qdisc` operations. Or wait for a PR for this to be done. https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6065

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is because of Windows Subsystem for Linux, it is limited.
If you install Oracle Virtual Box, and install an Ubuntu OS like 12.04 in a virtual machine, it will let you do it without complaints ;)